# Куда вставить onScroll?

Tags: getview, android, java, прокрутка

У меня всего один класс в приложении - main, вот как он устроен:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Фоновый поток, в котором скачивается и парсится JSON
        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        Log.d("qwe", "create MyTask: " + mt.hashCode());
        mt.execute();
    }

    //===============================================================================================

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
            // запускается метод для парсинга
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
        }
    }

    //===============================================================================================

    private void showTextList(JSONArray jArray) {
        // тут происходит парсинг json
    }

    //===============================================================================================

    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // несколько методов
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // код
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно вот какой код для скролла:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int from, int number, int counter) {

    if ((view.getAdapter() != null) && !((from + number) >= counter)) {
        from = from + number + 1;

        out.println(from + "----------------------");
        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        Log.d("qwe", "create MyTask: " + mt.hashCode());
        mt.execute();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
}
```

Comment: Сказал бы я как в том анекдоте - куда вставить :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы с `listView`  работаешь в `MyTask`, там устанавливаешь ему адаптер, там с ним и работай.  
Не забудьте интерфейс объявить.